# Replace Square Brackets for links on web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to do a parse of html content using jQuery/Javascript. I want to look for words between square brackets and change the whole word for a link.

Example:

```
<div>
   This is text inside a div. It has a reference to an [[Article]]
</div>
```

I'm trying to use Regular Expressions to change what's inside the double brackets into something like this:

```
<div>
   This is text inside a div. It has a reference to an <a href='/dictionary#Article'>Article</a>
</div>
```

I can find all instances of words between square brackets with this regex:

```
$('article').html().match(/[^[\]]+(?=])/g)
```

But don't know how to replace the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("div").html(function(i, html) {
    return html.replace(/\[\[(.+?)\]\]/g, "<a href='/dictionary#$1'>$1</a>");
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/y4N6e/

Comment: Beat me to it, very clean solution. This will trash handlers bound in nested elements, but it is not worth iterating over textNodes if there are no event handlers attached to descendants of the `div`.

Comment: While this is perfectly functional, performance may be unacceptable if you've got more than a couple types of thing being replaced. Regexes aren't very efficient. If you're making a wiki or a forum or something with lots of bracket-bounded tags, you may want to instead grab the indexes of the start and end of each tag and pass it off to an interpreter function.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté True, I also thought about it, and first wanted to provide `.contents()` solution. Finally, decided to go towards simple innerHTML change.

Comment: @user1618143 phpBB does bbcode parsing with regex as far as I know. Native string manipulation may be faster, though micro optimizations are the root of all evil.

Comment: @user1618143 Actually that is not true. Regular expressions are not always slower. You can set a benchmark and you will see that regex solution will do the job really faster for long strings.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the quick response/help. this works great. The links are not a lot (probably 4 or 5 per page), but I am worried about performance. I always thought using Regex would be faster/more efficient. 

What are my alternatives?

Comment: @amhed Don't worry about performance. This solution works quite fast. And yes, regex is very efficient for long strings.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
$('div').html($('div').html().replace(/\[\[([^\]]+)\]\]/, '<a href="/dictionary#$1">$1</a>')
```

should work.

But you should hava a look to [_.template method](http://underscorejs.org/#template)!.

Comment: retrieving `.text()` will eliminate all descendant elements and setting `.text()` will not create anchor elements, just textNodes.